# AndroidAnnotations - ViewById cannot be used on a private element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-annotations

**AndroidAnnotations version:** 4.3.1

**Android compile SDK version:** 26

**Kotlin version:** 1.1.3-2

I am trying to build app using Kotlin and AndroidAnnotaions. The build ends with

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

in `androidannotations.log` a is a ton of erros like

```
00:10:43.908 [RMI TCP Connection(91)-127.0.0.1] ERROR o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:77 - org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById cannot be used on a private element
```

thats the usage of `@ViewById` annotation

```
@ViewById
var description: TextView? = null
```

The same also happens with Pref annotated vars.

Is anybody else facing the same issue or it's just me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `lateinit`:

```
@ViewById
lateinit var description: TextView
```

The reason of getting this error may because of the behavior of the backing field. It is invisible by default and the `field` identifier can only be used in the accessors of the property. That's why you got `@ViewById cannot be used on a private element`.

The reason of why `lateinit` works is because it change the accessibility of the field. According to [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields):

> Late-Initialized properties are also exposed as fields. The visibility of the field will be the same as the visibility of lateinit property setter.

So, `@JvmField` is another solution for this problem.

```
@ViewById
@JvmField var helloTextView: TextView? = null
```

It also changes the visibility of the field as what the doc states:

> If you need to expose a Kotlin property as a field in Java, you need to annotate it with the @JvmField annotation. The field will have the same visibility as the underlying property. You can annotate a property with @JvmField if it has a backing field, is not private, does not have open, override or const modifiers, and is not a delegated property.

You may also refer to this [example](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/kotlin) and [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html) about Android frameworks using annotation processing.

Comment: Thank you, it's woking. Works for: @ViewById, @Bean, @Prefs, @StringRes, @RootContext... all non primitive objects.
However I still think that my approach should work too: `Without lateinit you'd have to declare a nullable type and add additional nullability checks.`

Comment: Yea, I think so at the beginning too. After some research, I found out a reasonable reason for that. I've updated the answer about the reason.

Comment: `JVMField` is asking for final field.